# How can I make an intersection of two columns of two tables and get the entire rows?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, join, sql-in

I have a SQLite table. Let's call it `people`.

| Name | Age |
| --- | --- |
| Jane | 50 |
| John | 80 |
| Alice | 46 |
| Mark | 25 |
| Harry | 33 |

I have another table `work`.

| Name | work_id |
| --- | --- |
| Jane | 1 |
| Amanda | 2 |
| Filip | 3 |
| Alice | 4 |
| Jack | 5 |
| Harry | 6 |

I'd like to get all rows whose name is in both `people` and `work`. But I do not only want the names. In fact I don't care about the names at all. I just need them to find the matching entries. I want the `work.work_id` and `people.age` columns of the matching rows. The result should look like this:

| work_id | age |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 |
| 4 | 46 |
| 6 | 33 |

Both tables can have hundreds to thousands of entries.

I also need a difference of the two i.e. The rows of `work` whose name isn't in `people`. But this should be solvable with the second solution I have outlined below.

I am doing this in Python3 using the builtin `sqlite3` module. But this should be a purely SQL problem independent of the SQL client.

## What I've tried

The obvious choice is to do an `INTERSECT`:

```sql
SELECT Name FROM people INTERSECT SELECT Name FROM work_id
```

As I said, I need the `Name` columns to find the intersection of the tables but I need the rows themselves to get the things I actually want, `people.age` and `work.work_id`, not the `Name`s.

---

The internet lead me to subqueries.

```sql
SELECT Name, Age FROM people where Name IN (SELECT Name FROM work)
```

This is a pretty powerful technique but I also need the `work_id` column of `work` so this isn't a solution.

Is this comparing each row in `people` with all rows of `work`? Is the number of comparisons `SELECT Count(*) FROM people` × `SELECT Count(*) FROM work` or is it somehow optimized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to select columns from both tables and this means you need an [`INNER JOIN`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp):

```
SELECT w.work_id,
       p.Age
FROM work AS w INNER JOIN people AS p
ON p.Name = w.Name;
```

For *the  rows of work whose name isn't in people* use `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM work
WHERE Name NOT IN (SELECT Name FROM people);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/J4YWGQr6).

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT work_id, Age
FROM people AS p
JOIN work AS w ON p.Name = w.Name;


SELECT name, work_id
FROM work
EXCEPT 
SELECT name
FROM people
```

Comment: Please explain your code. Also note your second query is invalid because EXCEPT requires an identic number of columns in both queries.

Comment: Ok) my level English is elementary, but I will try to write correctly. Thanks for the help and advice